# prove divisibility of a large number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I came across with the following question:

is the following correct: $$34 | (39^{16}-1)$$

After checking the calculator I've concluded it's true, but I was wondering if there is any other way doing it using some basic number theory skills.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) should be your first reflex.

Comment: Is it obvious to you that $2\mid39^{16}-1$, and do you know Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes I am familiar with fermat's little theorem, but how is it helpful here?

Comment: Since $39$ is coprime to $17$, that says $39^{17-1}\equiv1\bmod17$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So the answer is incorrect because it isnt divisible by 17 right?

Comment: For a compendium of techniques for answering questions like this please check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619) as well as hundreds of others, most but not all of them linked to that one.

Comment: No, $39^{16}-1$ **is** divisible by $17$

Comment: THis is a special case of [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) since  $\phi(34) = 16\,$ and $\gcd(39,34)=1.\ $ More generally see [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) in the linked dupe, and the links there.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $34=2\cdot 17$ and $2\mid (39^{16}-1)$. Next we need to show $17\mid (39^{16}-1)$. Fermat's little theorem is a shortcut. Or without applying Fermat's little theorem, we can do a direct computation, which gives

$$39^{16}-1\equiv5^{16}-1=25^8-1\equiv8^8-1\equiv(-4)^4-1\equiv(-1)^2-1=0\pmod  {17}$$

Comment: I dont understand your last steps, when you wrote -4

Comment: $8^8-1=64^4-1=(4\cdot 17-4)^4-1\equiv (-4)^4-1 \pmod{17}$ @YahavB

Comment: very neat and clean :O